# Present view controller and allow user to swipe back

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

Currently, I'm presenting a new view controller like this:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController {

    // Present fullscreen
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, this doesn't let me swipe from the left to go back to the previous controller. How can I enable this behaviour?

### Update

Here is my code now:

```
@objc func onNextButtonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to push controller instead of present ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push view controller to the navigational stack for that behaviour.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

For this to work the view controller that you're putting this code in must be embedded in a `UINavigationController`. For embedding the view controller into a navigation controller make sure the selected view controller does have the class that your code is contained in.

[image: screenshot 1]

And after embedding it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I embedded MyViewController and the presenting controller in a navigation controller and changed my code to match yours, but nothing is happening when I try to present. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: You just have to embed the view controller that you're putting this code into, into a navigation controller. Not the other one. try printing out navigationController to check if it's not nil, if it is the embedding hasn't worked.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it is `nil`. What else do I have to do to embed it besides clicking on the view controller in the storyboard and doing `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`?

Comment: You might be embedding the wrong view controller. Make sure it's the same view controller that has this tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: Just double checked, it's the same view controller. :/

Comment: The view controller isn't connected to anything else, is this a problem?

Comment: I've added the screenshots of how it'll look for you.

Comment: Strange, I've done that twice and still coming up as `nil` for whatever reason

Comment: How are you reaching this particular view controller? If you're using `instantiateViewController` for that particular VC and presenting then change it to use navigation controller identifier and `instantiateViewController` for presenting.

Comment: I get to this view controller by presenting a view controller from my tab bar controller (which is the root)

Comment: So, now instead of presenting the view controller, you need to present the navigation controller.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I still don't really understand why it showed `nil` for the navigation controller when I embedded the view controller though. Only when I created a navigation controller at the lowest level (where I present the first view controller from the tab bar controller) did it stop being `nil`.

Comment: It is pretty evident if you think about it. Even though you embedded the vc in nav vc you are still accessing vc instead of nav vc which by itself is a normal vc.